# In an email campaign, how can I programmatically track deliverability?

Tags: email, spam, email-confirmation

Services such as Pivotal Veracity, Email Advisor, and Return Path provide reports of how many messages in an email campaign were routed to the inbox, spam, and junk folders.

We use a system developed in-house to deliver our bi-monthly newsletter, and would like to be able to track how many of our messages are being directed to spam and junk folders.

How can we detect when this occurs?
(Note, we'd like to implement this system in-house rather than using an external service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't have a magic algorithm, they analyse how some ISP deal with email... 
as far as I know, there's no response from the ISP when he receives an email. It doesn't answer the sender with a "spam detected code"

Comment: I believe they also take a look at how many times the "Report Spam" button is clicked, which notifies the sender using a feedback loop. Usually a good indicator of where the message will go, along with IP reputation.

Comment: It's not from the SMTP server that notifies you (via the codes like "250 ok" and "550 no user") but you have to actually sign up for a feedback loop from major providers. We have one feeding PostageApp for our various IPs, so that we know when an IP has been flagged for sending spam emails. Sorry for the confusion!